# integration tests: spring mvc test framework post method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing

spring 3.2 introduced the spring mvc test framework and made it an official part of it, as stated in the documentation, i want to use this to test my controller, a method that handle a post request.

```
68     @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
69     public String addCarPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute NewCar car, BindingResult result){
70         if(result.hasErrors())
71         {
72             return "newcar" ;
73         }             
74         carService.addCar(car) ;        
75         return "redirect:/garage" ;     
76     }
```

here is my first attempt:

```
30 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
31 @ContextConfiguration("test-config.xml")
32 @WebAppConfiguration
33 public class GarageIntegrationTest {
       // ....
72     @Test public void testAddCarPost() throws Exception{
           // i didn't add any parameters to request.
73         this.mockMvc.perform(post("/garage/new"))
74             .andExpect(view().name("newcar")) ;
75     }
       // ....
    }
```

i want to test the @Valid, @RequestMapping, and @ModelAttribute, i didn't add any parameters to request, so a new `NewCar()` class is instantiated, all attribute of the class are initialized to null or 0, so the validator must detect that the new instance have errors and return the view "newcar", when i run this test i have a NullPointerException in the service `carService`, it's acting like `result.hasErrors()` has returned `false`, i missed something.

Comment: Can we see the NewCar code?

Comment: Run the test in debug mode and set breakpoints in your validator and in the addCarPost. You can check then if the validator is being called (and debug through it's logic to verify it is correct) and then check the result in controller to see if it is populated correctly.

Comment: the problem was in my text-config.xml file. thanks